# Export to the same directory in tortoisesvn to obtain unversioned directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed the TortoiseSVN version 1.7.13 and I'm trying to obtain an unversioned directory by exporting my working copy to the same folder.

I get a window explaining that I will have unversioned directories, but nothing happens after clicking Ok. Only a message window appears very quickly so that it isn't possible to read it. I can see full log of exported files but the overlay icons do not disappear. I still have files in this directory marked with icons.

Exporting into another empty directory works Ok.

I tried the all solutions suggested here at stackoverflow but no one worked. 
Deleting .svn is not possible with this version. Copying between two explorer windows fails. Dragging directory also fails.

Is it a bug or something? Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestion how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TortoiseSVN Export command only works correctly if the target is another directory.

If you want to manually export your working copy, perform a copy from your copy to another folder and delete the .svn folder.

Comment: This version of TortoiseSVN doesn't place .svn in each folder. There is only one .svn folder in root catalog.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behaviour. This doesn't answer your question?

Comment: I don't have .svn folders in every versioned directory. My TortoiseSVN version 1.7.13 removed them all, besides the one .svn folder in root directory that remained. Previously I had about 100 such dirs. That's why I can't delete it as you suggested.

Comment: I think I got your doubt now: you have an 1.6-version working copy. My suggestion is uninstall your current version and Export using an 1.6-version client. Download the last 1.6 version from TortoiseSVN here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.6.16/Application/

Comment: Do you think that TortoiseSVN v1.7 didn't clean up properly after the previously installed version 1.6?